# Update CFBundleVersion with git

Tags: ruby, xcode, github

How to Update CFBundleVersion of Xcode according to GitHub commit.
I was using since yesterday the SVN with ruby Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require "rubygems"
require "plist"

# fail if not run from Xcode
unless ENV['XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL']
    puts "error: Must be run from Xcode's Run Script Build Phase"
    exit false
end

revision = `svnversion`.chomp

if not $?.success?
    puts "error: svnversion failed"
    exit false
end

if revision =~ /[^0-9]/
    if ENV['CONFIGURATION'] == 'Release'
        puts "error: Working copy has mixed revision or uncommitted changes, cannot build in #{ENV['CONFIGURATION']} configuration"
        exit false
    end

    mixed_revision = revision
    revision = revision[/[0-9]+/] or '0'
    puts "warning: Mixed/flagged revision #{mixed_revision} corrected to #{revision}"
end

plistFile = "#{ENV['BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR']}/#{ENV['INFOPLIST_PATH']}"
`/usr/bin/plutil -convert xml1 "#{plistFile}"`
unless pl = Plist::parse_xml(plistFile) 
    puts "Could parse #{plistFile}"
    exit
end

freshPlFile = "#{ENV['SOURCE_ROOT']}/Resources/Info.plist"
`/usr/bin/plutil -convert xml1 "#{freshPlFile}"`
unless freshPl = Plist::parse_xml(freshPlFile)
    puts "Could parse #{freshPlFile}"
   exit
end


begin
    file = File.new("Resources/brands/#{ENV['BRAND_NAME']}/versions.txt", "r")
    while (line = file.gets)
        strp_line = line.strip
        strp_line.gsub!(/ /,'')
        strp_line.gsub!("ver",'')
        equal_pos = strp_line.index('=')
        str_len = strp_line.length
        if strp_line[0,equal_pos] == freshPl["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
            puts "Custom version found: #{strp_line[equal_pos+1,str_len -1]}"
            pl["CFBundleShortVersionString"] = strp_line[equal_pos+1,str_len -1]
            next
        end
    end
    file.close
rescue => err
    puts "Exception: #{err}"
    err
end

version = pl["CFBundleShortVersionString"].gsub(/ \([a-f0-9 \/:]*\)/, '')
# keep only the major and minor version number and add the revision
version.gsub!(/([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*).*/, "\\1.\\2.#{revision}");

pl["CFBundleShortVersionString"] = version
pl["CFBundleVersion"] = Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y%m%d%H")

pl.save_plist(plistFile)

`/usr/bin/plutil -convert binary1 #{plistFile}`

puts "#{plistFile}:"
puts "CFBundleVersion = #{pl["CFBundleVersion"]}"
puts "CFBundleShortVersionString = #{pl["CFBundleShortVersionString"]}"
```

I dont have any idea how to connect them with Github.

I tried to use this script but it doesn't work:

```
# add git tag + version number to Info.plist
version = `/usr/bin/env git describe`.chomp

puts "raw version "+version
version_fancy_re = /(\d*\.\d*)-?(\d*)-?/
version =~ version_fancy_re
commit_num = $2
if ( $2.empty? )
commit_num = "0"
end
fancy_version = ""+$1+"."+commit_num
puts "compatible: "+fancy_version

# backup
source_plist_path = File.join(ENV['PROJECT_DIR'], ENV['INFOPLIST_FILE'])
orig_plist = File.open( source_plist_path, "r").read;
File.open( source_plist_path+".bak", "w") { |file| file.write(orig_plist) }

# put in CFBundleVersion key
version_re = /([\t ]+<key>CFBundleVersion<\/key>\n[\t ]+<string>).*?(<\/string>)/
orig_plist =~ version_re
bundle_version_string = $1 + fancy_version + $2
orig_plist.gsub!(version_re, bundle_version_string)

# put in CFBundleShortVersionString key
version_re = /([\t ]+<key>CFBundleShortVersionString<\/key>\n[\t ]+<string>).*?(<\/string>)/
orig_plist =~ version_re
bundle_version_string = $1 + fancy_version + $2
orig_plist.gsub!(version_re, bundle_version_string)

# write
File.open(source_plist_path, "w") { |file| file.write(orig_plist) }
puts "Set version string to '#{fancy_version}'"
```

Any idea where am I doing the mistake?
I don't have experience with ruby, I will appreciate any help.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=increment+cfbundleversion+git&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us

Comment: Thanks @matt I have written that, what is wrong in my code which doesn't work.